# How do I convert tuple to dictionary then append to list

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is make a dictionary and append it to a masterList.

Ex.

```
x = [[(1,3),(4,6)],[(4,3),(2,4)]
```

What I want:

```
[{1:3, 4:6},{4:3,2:4}]
```

my code

```
masterList2 = []
for tuples in x:
    myDict = {}
    for singleTuple in tuples:
        myDict[singleTuple[0]] = singleTuple[1]
    masterList2.append(myDict)
print masterList2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict):

```
>>> x = [[(1,3),(4,6)],[(4,3),(2,4)]]
>>> [dict(lst) for lst in x]
[{1: 3, 4: 6}, {2: 4, 4: 3}]
>>>
```

Or, depending on your taste, you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and `dict`:

```
>>> x = [[(1,3),(4,6)],[(4,3),(2,4)]]
>>> map(dict, x)
[{1: 3, 4: 6}, {2: 4, 4: 3}]
>>>
```

Most Python programmers prefer the list comprehension though.

Answer (score 1):

```
[{key:value for key,value in i} for i in x]
```